# How can I load a module into another module using Elixir language?

Tags: elixir

I'm having hard time to load a module into another module using Elixir language.

For example, I have 2 files shown below:

a.ex

```
defmodule A do
  def a do
    IO.puts "A.a"
  end
end
```

b.ex

```
defmodule B do
  require A

  def b do
    IO.puts "B.b"
    A.a
  end
end

B.b
```

I tried to execute b.ex. Then I got error shown below:

```
$elixir b.ex
** (CompileError) b.ex:2: module A is not loaded and could not be found
```

Comment: there are 2 files in the same directory. a.ex and b.ex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your file `b.ex` remove the B.b from the last line

Then in your project directory run Iex like so

```
iex -S mix
```

This will load iex and load your modules correcly

Then you can just do `B.b`

and you'll see:

```
B.b
A.a
:ok
```

Also, make sure your `a.ex` and `b.ex` files are in the `lib/` directory of your elixir project

Comment: @HideshiOgoshi you should accept the answer if it worked

Comment: I tried running same code but unable to run. I ran "iex -S mix" in command prompt "G:\work\Project1>iex -S mix"  where I have lib\ProjectName folder within  G:\work\Project1.  I get following

 iex(1)> B.b
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function B.b/0 is undefined (module B is not available)
    B.b()